# How do I add attributes to the tags in dexml?

Tags: python, xml, xml-serialization

I am using this Python XML Serialization library [dexml](http://pythonhosted.org/dexml/). I can't quite figure out how to put attributes on some of the tags in this xml I am generating from an object. I read through the documentation and, unless I can't read, I can't find a good explanation on how.

Here is the code involved.

```
import dexml
import urllib2
from dexml import fields
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Section(dexml.Model):
    section = fields.String()
    entries = fields.List(fields.String(tagname="Entry"))
    # Add something for href here, maybe?

class AtoZ(dexml.Model):
    list = fields.List(Section)

def makeSoup(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

def main():
    soup = makeSoup("http://www.somewebsite.com")

    sectionList = []

    # You might wonder about the length of this; I *could* split it up
    # into variables to make it shorter. Also, the chaining is because
    # the 'li' I want are only inside of a <ul class="Nav_fm>".
    for li in soup.find('ul', {'class':"Nav_fm"}).find_all('li', {'class':"MenuLevel_0"}):
    atzSection = Section()
    atzSection.section = li.a.string

    for innerLi in li.find_all('li', {'class':"MenuLevel_1"}):
        atzSection.entries.append(innerLi.a.string)
        # Somehow store innlerLi.a['href'] in atzSection

    sectionList.append(atzSection)

    atzList = AtoZ(list=sectionList)

    f = open("C:\\atoz.xml", "w")
    f.write(atzList.render(pretty=True))
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the resultant XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AtoZ>
    <Section section="#">
        <Entry>...</Entry>
        <Entry>...</Entry>
        <Entry>...</Entry>
        <Entry>...</Entry>
    </Section>
    ...
    <Section section="Z">
        <Entry>...</Entry>
        <Entry>...</Entry>
        <Entry>...</Entry>
        <Entry>...</Entry>
    </Section>
</AtoZ>
```

I want to have `<Entry href="...">...</Entry>` for each `<Entry>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try redefining Section.entries to be a List of Entry items like this:

```
class Entry(dexml.Model):
    href = fields.String() 
    ...

class Section(dexml.Model):
    section = fields.String()
    entries = fields.List(fields.Model(Entry), tagname='Entry')
```

Check out the dexml [test code](https://github.com/rfk/dexml/blob/master/dexml/test.py) - lots of good illustrations on how to use it beyond what the documentation describes.